# Is db4o object manager enterprise free? Where can I download it? Is it a standalone application?

Tags: java, eclipse, db4o

As per the title I have three parts to this question...

Is db4o object manager enterprise free?
-I saw a blog post about it being free.

Where can I download it?
-the website is rather unclear

Is it a standalone application?
-I seem to remember it was an eclipse plugin but this was awhile ago.  Is there an Intellij plugin?

Comment: OK this whole post is really screwed up. I don't see anything particularly wrong with the OP's question (aside perhaps from it not being *totally* coding related) -- and yet it has -2, which is undeserved. The "Best Answer" is in fact henchman's comment on Gamlor's answer, although Gamlor's answer is decent enough. NerdK's answer is not particularly great, but surely doesn't deserve a -1 any more than Benju deserves -2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a part of the [db4o-distribution.](http://www.db4o.com/DownloadNow.aspx)
2. It's a part of the db4o-distribution. When you unzip (or install) the db4o-distribution, it's in the `ome`-directory.
3. It's a Eclipse-plugin for the Java-platform and a Visual Studio plugin for the .NET-platform. There's a [stand-alone-port](http://code.google.com/p/domr/), but I'm not sure how active that is developed maintained.

Comment: @OP: If you licence your own project with GPL (eg: provide sourcecode to everybody who gets the binaries), you can use db4o for free. Otherwise, you will have to get a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.db4o.com/DownloadNow.aspx

It has a free GPL version.